# Video rotated after importing it for motion tracking

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm importing a video file for motion tracking, that has been shot on a phone. If I open it with Windows Media Player or After Effects it's not rotated, but it is when I import it to Blender. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Phones typically provide the rotation orientation via a hint in the wrapper metadata. Given it is a hint tag, many pieces of software will ignore it.